# how to create another equation from continuous state of s-function results

Tags: matlab, simulink

i hope that some one can help me...

This is regarding to my s-function m-file which contains 11 ODE equation.

> > > > sys(1) = -Kd*x(1) - (Fev*I.*x(3).*(1 - x(2))*Kp);
> > > >
> > > > sys (2) = Kp*(1 - x(2)).*x(3);
> > > >
> > > > sys(3) = (-Fev*x(3).*x(3).*(1 - x(2))./(1 + Fev*x(2))).*Kp
> > > >
> > > > untill sys(11)

my 12 and 13 equation is from 11 ODE equation, as below:

> > > > dl = (x(3)+x(5) / x(8) +x(3))*102;
> > > >
> > > > dk = (x(6) +x(4) / x(7) + x(9)) *102 ;

But i do not know how to create 12 and 13 equation in s-function file?should i put these equations in discrete state?

Comment: Ok, I think we can handle this one, but I need to understand the problem a bit better.  What are sys(1)-system(11)?  Are they state variables?  Also, I would highly recommend *not* using an s-function for such a simple system.  Either draw out the system in simulink, or use an embedded m block.  Let me know!

Comment: Also, why not do this through the ode m functions?  Get back with me and we'll see if we can get you an answer.

Comment: yes,they are first principle model describing the process.sys(1)-sys(11) is a differential equation and they was initiator concentration, conversion, reactor temperature, etc. Meanwhile dl and dk are also output variables and they can be calculated from the result of differential equation. if i draw out in simulink, do i need to use mathematical operation block diagram or other simple block that can solve more faster?i have try to put in ode equation but i gor this error.....

Comment: the error is...."State derivatives returned by S-function 'reactor_sfcn' in 'wo_pid2/S-Function1' during flag=1 call must be a real vector of length 13."

Comment: macduff, u give me an idea to use embedded matlab function block diagram and its working.thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend not using an s-function for such a simple system. Either draw out the system in simulink, or use an embedded m block.